# htaccess rewrite doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm new with htaccess and with a little help I could write this, but I'm having some problems and I don't know how to solve them

```
# General setup
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on 
Options -Indexes
CheckSpelling off

# rewrite php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# rewrite html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# error pages
ErrorDocument 404 error
```

Problems:

1. I'd like to transform somefile?var=value to somefile/value and it doesn't work
2. If I write somefile/anything I get somefile without css style instead of being redirect to the error page
3. As I'm new with htacess I don't know if that file is secure enough

What I'd like:

1. Redirect any extension to a filename file (with no extension)
2. Protect my htaccess and directory and files
3. redirect any users?id=id_user to users/username

Do you know any way to construct the htaccess online? or Do you have any idea or advice to give me?
Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting CSS probably because your links are relative URLs, and when you have multiple paths in your URL, the relative links *all break*. You can try adding this to your page headers:

```
<base href="/" />
```

The `somefile/anything` is because the `-f` together with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} actually checks for path info requests, so you want to use this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
```

For values, try adding this before your other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php\?var=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2?%3 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?var=$2 [L,QSA]
```

For users, you're not going to be able to use htaccess because the URL `/users?id=userid` **does not contain the username**. Mod_rewrite has no idea what user ID maps to what user name. You'll need to do this using a php script (like `users.php`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. base href tag and request_uri replace you are right. But, the variables are not loaded when I put them in the address bar. I put RewriteRule ^page/$1$ page?var=$1 [L,QSA] and if I write page/basic the basic value are not loaded as var value... so you know what could be happen? Thanks again!!

Comment: @user3132921 do you have multiviews turned on? Try turning it off: `Options -Multiviews`

Comment: No, I don't have multiviews on. Actually the redirect works fine but the value of the variable is not working... :(